# SwiftUI Font smallCaps() not working with italic()

Tags: fonts, swiftui, italic, smallcaps

```
    extension Font {

        public static let Heading1: Font = system(size: 34, weight: .black, design: .default)
        .smallCaps()
        .italic()
    }
```

I can make the font all caps OR italic - but not both. Anybody know how to get around this? Without typing the String out in caps to begin with. I even tried importing BlackItalic as a custom font and still had the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of Apple platform built-in font support both *italic-smallcap* features combination. System *San Francisco* is the most font-feature capable font supports *smallcap* for *regular* and *bold*, but not for *italic*.

[image: demo1][image: demo2]

Small caps are rare feature, and rare fonts support it, but even more rare, unique, fonts support both.

Here is quotation from Wikipedia [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps).. pay attention on last sentence.

> Small capitals are not found in all fonts, as they were primarily used
>   within body text and so are often not found in fonts that are not
>   intended for this purpose, such as many sans-serif families.[6] Some
>   font families, especially digitisations of older metal type designs,
>   often lack small caps in bold or italics, only having them in the
>   regular or roman style.[7] This is because they were normally only
>   used in body text and cutting bold and italic small caps was thought
>   unnecessary.[a]

See also: 
[AHIG Typography](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/)

Comment: Ah ok, I see. In that case do you know how I could use .uppercased() instead? I am using a LocalizedStringKey