# SwiftUI Font how to use uppercased() with LocalizedStringKey

Tags: fonts, swiftui, uppercase, italic, smallcaps

I am trying to create a Font style that is both italic and uppercase. I am also using LocalizedStringKey to set my String. I tried using smallCaps() but this didn't work with italic() as answered [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61369580/swiftui-font-smallcaps-not-working-with-italic/61371169#61371169) and if I try to use uppercased() on the LocalizedStringKey it just sets the key to uppercase rather than the String.

Anyone know a solution?

```
 extension Font {
    public static let Heading1: Font = system(size: 34, weight: .black, design: .default).italic()
}

Text("HELLO_WORLD").font(.Heading1)
```

Comment: I have also tried Text("HELLO_WORLD".uppercased(with: Locale.current)).font(.Heading1) 
but this is still just sets  the key to uppercase not the string –

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

```
Text(NSLocalizedString("HELLO_WORLD", comment: "").uppercased())
    .font(.Heading1)
```